# cmd command to delete not containing (non pdf files) from a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi I want to delete non pdf files from Temp folder using cmd "del" command.

So need to include non pdf part in to following cmd command.

cm /c del /Q c:\Temp

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d c:\temp
for %%i in (*) do (
  if /i "%%~xi" neq ".pdf" ECHO del "%%i"
)
```

for every file: if the extension is not `.pdf` then delete it.

Remove the `ECHO` if the ouptut satisfies you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. provided answer is not working. I tried cmd /c del /Q c:\temp\*.* . but the problem is all files will delete.

Comment: there is a typo worm attack on this - second % is missing in front of this: %~xi, so the line should look:  if "%%~xi" neq ".pdf" ECHO del %%i

Comment: Parameter for `del` should use quotes in case there are space characters in the filename.  `del "%%~i"`

Comment: The comparison of the file extension should be done in a case-insensitive manner (add the `/I` switch to `if`) as Windows does not care about the case also...